# How to access DOM from ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have an ion-input like this.

```
<ion-item>
<ion-input #nameInput id="nameInput" class="item-name-input" 
type="text" value="" placeholder="Add to wishlist" [(ngModel)]="itemNameInput" clearInput>
</ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

How can I access the DOM and clear the input after submission?

I used,

```
this.itemNameInput = "";
```

But sometimes it gives an error when building the project. 
So how can I do this in ionic 3?

Comment: declare `itemNameInput = ""`;

Comment: "But sometimes it gives an error when building the project" so fix that error first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code is expected to work by `this.itemNameInput=""`, if it's not working by any means you can try the javascript way of clearing values in DOM.

You can access DOM directly by using `document.getElementById("currentScore").innerHTML` where currentScore can be like `<div id="currentScore">{{scoreElapsed}}</div>` in HTML.

`document.getElementById("currentScore").innerHTML = "";` will empty the content inside the DOM